# Modify WWW-Authenticate headers handling in Firefox

Tags: firefox, authentication, http-authentication

I have a web application that requires authentication. It sends 2 HTTP headers, in the following order:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

When I navigate to this application with Internet Explorer or Chrome, these browsers select the Negotiate protocol to perform integrated Windows authentication (client computers and server are member of the same Active Directory domain). These browsers read all WWW-Authenticate headers, and choose the strongest protocol available to perform authentication.

From what I observes, Firefox behaves differently. It processes the headers in order. So it first shows a login prompt to the user (basic authentication); if the user clicks "Cancel", or basic auth fails, it uses the second protocol, Negotiate and performs SSO as well.

This is not user friendly. I know that we should modify the application, however it is not possible at the moment.

So my question is: is there a way to modify how Firefox handles WWW-Authenticate headers? A parameter in "about:config" maybe? I would like that it behaves like IE and Chrome, and uses Negotiate first.